# Also see filename when using an Xcode #imageLiteral

Tags: xcode, image-literals

The fairly recent [`#imageLiteral`](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/be-literal-76e9b4389eda) in Xcode is neat. I especially like the safety it provides: the code won't compile if you're using an image that doesn't exist so the return type is a non optional image that you know will be available.

However, I find the tiny single character image icon that shows in Xcode's editor cute but fairly useless. I'd much rather see the file name there instead, which is what's sitting there in the underlying source code.

Is there some other way of coaxing Xcode to show me the file's name inline, instead of, or as well as, the iconic image representation? Perhaps an Xcode setting?

Answer (score 1):

Cool trick: Comment out the line to see the exact name of the image file!

Comment: Oh really? Nice – I'll have to try that! … might be worth checking the "comparison" editor too, that's often useful for seeing the actual text.

Answer (score 0):

If you click other at the bottom of the image representation it will open up so you can choose by file name.  Hope that helps.